# How do I prevent water from leaking behind my new gutters?

Tags: gutters, leaks

I had a new roof installed along with gutter and gutter guards last year. Over the past few months I’ve noticed that after it rains there’s always the same stretch of gutter that drips water from behind it. In that portion there’s about a one inch gap between the gutter and fascia.

When I asked the roofer to look at it this was the response I received:

Well I looked at it other day your gutter screen goes under shingles and on a low pitch roof where it kinda flattens out the screens hold the shingles up just enough to let water wick back or run backwards and leak in between the gutter and fascia. Not exactly sure I have a good solution for that or not.

Is there a quick fix I can do on my own like use some silicone or is there something to recommend to the roofer? Don’t want to leave this alone because it seems like water damage waiting to happen.

Comment: Pictures would really help.  Hard to make any recommendations just based on your description.

Comment: Your gutter screens should not go under the shingles.  There should not be a 1 inch gap between the gutter and fascia.

Comment: @RMDman that's not true, there are some that are flat on the back for that purpose.